# How to get NetBeans to display the build.xml file in the project tree?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I want to edit build.xml in NetBeans, but it isn't included in the project source tree under **Projects**. Is there a way to get it to show up in the project source tree? (It is under the **Files** window.)

I can open it explicitly because I know where it is, but it would be easier for me and other project engineers to just double-click on a file in the source tree.

Comment: Just right click on it in the files tab and select open?